# What is the most idiomatic way to store the endpoint for an API, if it is subject to change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storage, integrity

I am building a React app and as part of it, I have a backend Express server which runs on a local port, however this is due to change on deployment, and maybe more times in the future. What would be the best way to store the address of this API in the frontend?

Currently I use:
`localStorage.setItem("apiEndpoint", "http://10.1.1.177:8080");` but that feels quite hacky and insecure.

I don't know the specific problem with that approach as this is set on every page load, meaning it can't be changed, but it feels wrong to do.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't set the URL as a variable containing that url in the build process?

Comment: Rather than storing it inside your app, I would have some kind of central "authority" (e.g. a server) which takes some kind of app identifier and resolves it to an API url. For example, a simple endpoint which would map "app1" -> "http://10.1.1.177:8080", "app2" -> "http://10.1.1.178:8080". This way you can change API url without updating your clients too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables with React. Basically, this will allow you to use a .env file and you can name the endpoint as API_ENDPOINT=http://10.1.1.177:8080 for your development environment. On your production environment, you can use a different url but with the same API_ENDPOINT name.

You can reference the below link

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: The major downside of this is you now need a separate build per environment, rather than being able to promote a tested asset between environments. I've expanded on this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't realise React had support for environment variables. I'll give this a try!